# Hard whitespace

Tags: spacing, verbatim, plain-tex

I am using plainTeX and would like to typeset some (python) code examples.
Switching to `\tt` gets me partway there, but I (obviously) need
the whitespace respected. Is there a trick for doing this? The last time I needed this I ended up writing a preprocessor that inserted appropriate `\` everywhere.
Oh dear, I guess I also need to eliminate paragraph indenting, and force newlines.

Comment: Did the answers help you in the end? If so it might be time to accept one to conclude this thread. If not please point out what is still missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I would use `\verbatim` from `eplain`.

```
\input eplain

\verbatim
def foo():
    pass
|endverbatim
\bye
```

Answer (score 13):

In general TH.'s answer is preferable. It also disables other special characters like `\` which might be used in the Python code.

But here the answer about the spaces, line endings and parindent:
You can make plainTeX or LaTeX print all spaces using `\obeyspaces`. For line endings there is `\obeylines` which actually turns them into paragraphs (`\par`). The paragraph indention can be removed by setting `\parindent=0pt`.

This should be done inside a group of course. Make sure to comment all line endings for you code including the trailing `\endgroup` (or `}`), otherwise they will be printed as well.

```
\begingroup
\parindent=0pt\relax
\obeyspaces%
\let =\ %
\obeylines%

Your python code

\endgroup%
```

Comment: It appears that `\obeyspaces` in this case does not respect the indent (whitespace at the start of the line), only whitespace in the middle of the line.

Comment: @Simon: Ok, that's funny. Add `\let =\ %` behind `\obeylines` to avoid this. The space is made active, i.e. is a macro which produces a space like `\space`. Using the above line it will use `\ ` instead.

Comment: @Martin: maybe you can add an explanation why the simple `\obeyspaces\obeylines` doesn't do the trick. The fact is that `\obeylines` turns the end-of-line into `\par` and a normal space doesn't start horizontal mode (and in vertical mode spaces are ignored), while `\ ` does start horizontal mode.

Comment: I'm new to plain tex, so if I wrap all of this inside a macro, there's an error concerning `\let =\ %`. What's wrong? ("Missing control sequence inserted.")

Answer (score 6):

there's a rather elaborate verbatim routine in the tugboat plain macros, in the file `tugboat.sty`. it's too long to repeat here, but the code is pretty well documented and can probably be "lifted" without too much hassle.  the rationale for developing this code was exactly what was asked for here -- observing precise spacing, especially at the beginnings of code lines, to be able to present tex macro code intelligibly.

`tugboat.sty` is on tex live in the `/tex/plain/tugboat-plain` area, and also [on ctan](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/plain/contrib/tugboat/tugboat.sty).

Answer (score 5):

I have tried to use plain TeX to typeset source code (in many languages). As it proved to be  a hard task, and even harder if you wanted some eye candy like keyword highlighting, nowadays I prefer to use LaTeX to do the job with the listing environment and to include the output as a figure.

Ex:

```
% dclass and package loading
\usepackage{listings}

% stuff, stuff, stuff,

\lstset{
    rulecolor=\color{BlockGray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{TopGray},
    frame=shadowbox,
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{yellow},
    numberblanklines=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    showstringspaces=false,
}

% stuff, stuff, stuff,

\begin{document}

% stuff, stuff, stuff,

\begin{lstlisting}
from twisted.internet import reactor

def helloWorld():
    print "Hello World!"

reactor.callWhenRunning(helloWorld)
reactor.callWhenRunning(reactor.stop)

reactor.run()
\end{lstlisting}

% stuff, stuff, stuff,
```

Comment: Please note the `plain-tex`-tag of the OP.

Comment: Yep, I noticed since the beginning. So, I edited my post so I could better explain what I'm use to do when I want to typeset source code.

Comment: @PEdroArthur: Welcome to TeX.SX. Note that this isn't a normal forum, but a question and answer site with much stricter rules. Please only provide answers to the asked questions, i.e. solutions to the stated problems. The OP was asking about a plainTeX solution and your post doesn't address this. It's nice that you want to share the solutions which work for you, but it qualifies as an answer to the question.

Comment: I don't get it straight, mainly 'cause your last sentence. Let me try to understand your thoughts.What you are arguing is that it is better to have no answer|solution if it isn't completely aligned with the OP question than a solution that fits someone "same" purpose but is made-up with an extra set of tools? Is this what you meant?

Comment: @PEdroArthur The issue, I think, is more that there have been a number of suggested solutions using plain TeX, and using plain TeX is one of the main requirements of the question. Because your suggestion does not use plain TeX, it can't be considered a valid answer, and is superfluous.

Comment: @PEdroArthur: Please use `@` followed by user name so that the user is notified. Owners of the question or answer are always notified about any comment. And yes, we want only answers to the asked questions, and no opinions or wide striving discussions etc. Telling the OP to not use plainTeX as planned but use LaTeX+`listings` because you couldn't do it in plainTeX isn't that helpful as well. Like I said, this is not a normal forum and has much stricter rules then one. Have a look around and also visit our [meta site](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/) and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @Edd when I post my answer there were no other answer (or it arrived concurrently with the others). So, I thought it may be pleasant for the OP to have something useful or that, at least, works to someone with a similar problem. @Martin Ok, got it. However, the main argument of my answer was explicitly told: when you typeset code in a lot of languages and uses chromatic effects to make it easier to understand, it is infeasible to keep them in plainTeX (actually not infeasible, but poorly pragmatical). Only to make it clear. Sorry for the pointless discussion.

Comment: @PEdroArthur: I have also found to my own detriment that one must stick to the OP's question and nothing else. If someone works in plainTeX without studying the TeXbook (especially App E were the answer to this question is) then he is in for a long suffering. My feeling is also switch to Latex and use listings, but it is not the right answer.

Comment: @Martin and Pedro: I think this answer is fine. It says use LaTeX to generate the listing and then include that as a graphic in the plain TeX document. The answer would be better if it included a complete example for making the listing in LaTeX (including document class and any packages needed) as well as including the code necessary to include it as a graphic in the plain TeX document.

Comment: @Edd: That goes for you too. Answers about graphics of the form "use this external tool that's included with your TeX distro and then include it in your document" are fine. This is analogous.

Comment: @PEdroArthur: Note that only the first `@` user is notified (plus the owner of the question/answer). You will have to split your comment into multiple ones.

Comment: @TH oh, the document class isn't so relevant and no other package is needed. However, sometimes I find useful to set document class as Beamer (usually for Java code excerpts) or to include the package a4wide for other classes (long listings in any language). To include the listing as an EPS figure, just do as usual: `\epsfbox{codelistingfile.eps}`

Comment: @PEdro: I'd probably use `graphicx` in plain TeX, but my point was that a complete answer would turn your answer from a fine one into a good one.