# Environment for respecting spaces

Tags: spacing, macros

I am using XeLaTeX and I want to create a new environment which — among other things — should respect all spaces. [The code presented in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15163/104252) works well for me. But how to create a new environment enforcing this behaviour? I cannot make the `\let =\ %` work. Furthermore the spaces get removed again, when I put my own environment inside another one, for example a table. Do you have any ideas? Unfortunately I'm not into the subtleties of macro programming. (I do not want to have a `verbatim` environment, I still want to use usual TeX commands, but I have to typeset many spaces which I want to be respected) Best

This is my code

```
\newenvironment{activespaces}{
\begingroup
\parindent=0pt\relax%
\obeyspaces%
\obeylines%
}{
\endgroup
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! :) Quick tip - always leave a blank line before a code block, or it won't be formatted properly.

Comment: How did you specify the `tabular` column? If you use a `p{3in}` (or some such) column specifier, it should work inside a table cell.

Comment: Thanks, by such a specification it works. But if I use it in a new command again, like \newcommand{\sometext}{\begin{activespaces} s   ome  th ing \end{activespaces}}, it fails again. Is there no way to make it robust?

Comment: you could obeyspaces everywhere but if you just want it locally, then as all "verbatim" like commands, it will not work in the argument of another command. `\newcommand{\sometext}{\begin{activespaces} s           ome th ing \end{activespaces}}` the `activespaces` environment does nothing useful as the consecutive spaces between `s` and `ome` have already been read as a single space token before `\begin{activespaces}` is executed.

Comment: you are missing a `%` in the first line, and do not need `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` (an environment is already a group) however as noted above no such command can work in the argument of another macro.

Comment: I don't know the actual problem. But try `alltt` package which works like `verbatim` environment but allows macros.